# How do I make a div box fade in AND out using only one button?

Tags: css, html, onclick, fadein

**CSS/HTML styled codes only. Jquery and the like will not work for my page.**

I am trying to make it so each box responds to the circle shaped tab above it. 
I want the boxes to start out as being invisible/faded but to appear when the corresponding circle tab is clicked.
Likewise, I would like the option for the boxes to be able to disappear after clicking the button a second time, reverting to its original invisible/faded out state.

I am not sure whether I should be using a fadeout/fadein element or an onclick one as I am new to this idea. 
I've read some pages about it but I can't seem to incorporate it into my own codes, and the ones that I thought might have been useful ended up being Jquery. 
I've seen it done before similarly to how I wish to use them and I would like to understand it better.

I apologize if something of this nature has been asked already, but I couldn't find any examples to help me and I've been searching for quite some time now. All I know about coding is what I've taught myself which is a struggle on its own. I'd appreciate any feedback.

*CSS:*

```
body {
    background-color: #666;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#profile {
    border: 0px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
/*--Content--*/
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 420px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1170px;
}
.textbox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 120px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    overflow: auto;
}
/*--Navigation--*/
#nav {
    top: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 90px;
}
#nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 3px 0;
}
/*--Nav Tabs--*/
#circle {
    position: fixed;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #fff, inset 0 0 10px #6699cc;
    margin: 3px 0 0 30px;
}
#circle:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="navbox">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#1"><div id="circle"></div></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#2"><div id="circle"></div></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#3"><div id="circle"></div></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<a name="1"></a>

    <div class="textbox">Info 1.</div>
<a name="2"></a>

    <div class="textbox">Info 2.</div>
<a name="3"></a>

    <div class="textbox">Info 3.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can write your own code, thankyouverymuch. This is not a question.

Comment: Please avoid sympathy upvotes.

Comment: You mention **"Jquery and the like will not work for my page"** - what about javascript? Just give the element an inline-style and set the opacity attribute of the style with javascript.

Comment: You can use css transition with opacity attribute to fade in or out using pure css.

Comment: Ah,I wasn’t trying to gain any sympathy votes @bjb568.This is my first question posted so I wasn’t expecting it to be perfect;I was only trying to be polite.If I knew how to write this code I'd gladly do so myself.My posting isn’t act of being lazy,I’ve been trying out things I’ve read elsewhere and I'll continue to do so until I figure it out.Any help is simply appreciated.Despite the rude undertone,I’m still happy you took the time to look over my question.I shall update the code to be more accommodating, as you implied.To everyone who has listed a suggestion,thank you,I will try them out.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is using `labels`, `inputs` with `input:checked` and an `adjacent child selector`.

Here's a demo demonstrating:

http://jsfiddle.net/7DUFS/

Comment: Thank you! It works on my page. I'll try working with this and see what I come up with. :)

Comment: Great to hear! Good luck implementing. If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)